# Elementary group theory: counting the order of cosets.

Tags: group-theory

If $H\le G$ and $|H|= n$ then what is $|xHx^{-1}|$ where $x\in G$?

Is it simply $n$, because if $x\in H$ then $|xHx^{-1}|=|H|=n$ and if $x\notin H$ then clearly $|xHx^{-1}|=n$ as well.

Is this correction reasoning?

Answer (score 2):

You did not show why it is clear that $|x H x^{-1}|=|H|$ in either case..... For $h\in H$ let $f(h)=x h x^{-1}.$ Then for $h_1,h_2\in H$ we have $$f(h_1)=f(h_2)\iff x h_1 x^{-1}=x h_2 x^{-1}\iff x h_1=x h_2\iff h_1=h_2.$$ So $f$ is 1-to-1 so $$|x H x^{-1}|=|\{f(h):h\in H\}|=|H|.$$

Answer (score 1):

Conjugation is an automorphism and therefore preserves size.

Comment: it's enought that conjugation is injective.